# Amazon SES - configure to only send transactional emails but not receive emails?

Tags: amazon-ses

I've noticed mailgun no longer offers free 10000 emails per month so I'm looking for a cheaper alternative.

I've come across Amazon SES (https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/) which appears to be a lot cheaper however I note you also get charged for receiving emails as well including spam.

Can SES be configured to only send emails but not receive as I would only want to use it to send emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AWS SES not all the regions are able to receive mails.

Complete list is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ses.html

However, if You would like to send emails using SES, You can disable all of the rule sets for receiving emails(if You have some, or just not create one). Those should be enough for Your case.